# Gesture recogniser is impacting other functionality

Tags: ios, swift

I have a gesture recogniser that is stopping the collectionView function from working properly. Example code is added below.

The view controller has a collection view, where cells can be deleted in a similar way to how apps are deleted on an iPhone home screen. The user long presses the screen for the collection cells to start shaking and stops shaking once the screen is tapped (not on the delete button for the cells).

Now that this delete functionality is working, I can no longer click on the cells to open a new view controller with the associated information. Is there a way to add a conditional so that the tapRecognizer only happens while the cells are shaking, so that the collectionView function works when a cell in the collection view is tapped?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed))

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapPressed))

    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}


//Tap screen
@objc func tapPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
    stopCellShaking()
}
```

```
//Open the information for the selected cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        //Function to open new screen
        showInformation(chosenCell: exampleList[indexPath.row])

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a conditional so that the tapRecognizer only happens while the cells are shaking

Absolutely. In general, just turn off the tap recognizer by setting its `isEnabled` to `false`. When the shaking starts (long press), set the tap gesture recognizer's `isEnabled` to `true`.